# Python kernel dies while doing a division in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, spyder

I have a csv the size is about 94.4 MB and it contains 143,940 rows and 63 columns. I am just trying to divide two columns and outputting the value in another column. The code I am executing is a very simple code.

```
DF['Col3'] = DF['Col1'] / DF['Col2']
```

Every time I execute this piece of code on my spyder3 or Jupyter Notebook the kernel dies I used to execute this code before but I dint have any problem. Now I get the error message

> Kernel died, restarting

I am running python 2.7 and anaconda version 4.3.14 pandas version 0.19.2 on my laptop which has a 8 GB RAM. of which only 1 GB is utilized prior to running this code and utilizes 100% when I am running this code.

If there are any suggestions please guide. Thank you

Comment: And how should we know what to do when we don't know what's in the file and how you read it? Note that "kernel died" probably means "segmentation fault" so you need to include some sort of traceback (gdb-like) so we can actually know what's going wrong. Does it work in a Python shell? Does it work for other csv data? Does it work for older pandas versions? Did you consider posting this as a bug on the pandas issue tracker? It seems like this is very likely a bug in pandas.

Comment: If you read the file using `pd.read_csv()` you could try to specify `engine='python'`. It's unlikely a pure-python implementation segfaults and if it fails there will be a complete traceback.

Comment: I have read the file using pd.read_csv(). It does not work in python shell as well. The file contains Purchase Order data of spend information with dates and contract information hence the data is confidential. All my other codes are working fine the problem is only with the place where I am doing the calculation.

Comment: I tried this and got the error `Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`

Comment: you don't need to share the original data, just something to reproduce the error. Regarding the exception: Could you include [edit] that into the question as well?

Comment: So add the U flag when opening the file for universal-newline mode. `fid = open(filename, 'rU')
data = csv.reader(fid)`

Comment: I had the same problem each time I was broadcasting a division. See if this link can help you: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2031

Comment: After scanning through the dataset I found that the column had taken text data in 2 cells which caused this issue I corrected that and it worked again. Ideally it should have considered that field as a string and thrown up some other kind of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/discussions/weeks/4/threads/VrKtIe-TEeahuQ5PjaKRFg

Apparently the kernel has issues with division between two series when there are NaNs involved. I solved the issue by replacing the "/" operator with the div() method as suggested.

Instead of doing `df.col1 / df.col2`, you can do `df.col1.div(df.col2)`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html

Comment: Current link is broken or not accessible to those not enrolled. Could you post the div() method here?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought it was accessible from the outside. Instead of doing `df.col1 / df.col2`, you can do `df.col1.div(df.col2)`. I just edited my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks! I've also been using `df.col1.divide(df.col2)`

Comment: you're welcome! Apparently both methods do the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654181/difference-between-dataframe-div-and-dataframe-divide-in-pandas