# Difference between DataFrame.div and DataFrame.divide in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to divide elements of a one column of pandas data frame with same row index elements of another column. While trying to find library functions to achieve this, I came across two functions [DataFrame.div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and [DataFrame.divide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html). Their documentations are very similar and I am wondering what the differences between them might be. Are there any differences between them? Is their internal implementation different? If yes, how so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are both aliases for the function [`pd.DataFrame.truediv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truediv.html), and they all do the same thing - perform index-aligned division along the given axis.

`truediv` is one of the main operations specified in the [`_op_descriptions`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops.py#L194) data-structure in `pandas/core/ops.py`. `div` and `divide` are later created as references to this.